# Visualize graph with correct names of vertices (igraph for r)

Tags: r, igraph

I'm working on `igraph` package on `r`:

```
library(igraph)
actors <- data.frame(name=c("Alice", "Bob", "Cecil", "David",
                        "Esmeralda"))
relations <- data.frame(from=c("Bob", "Cecil", "Cecil", "David",
                           "David", "Esmeralda"),
                    to=c("Alice", "Bob", "Alice", "Alice", "Bob", "Alice"))
g <- graph_from_data_frame(relations, directed=TRUE, vertices=actors)

write_graph(g, "g.graphml", "graphml")
```

I downloaded the Socnetv software [Socnetv](http://%20https://socnetv.org), which accepts the graphml format as input. It is used to view the network. Anyway, for graph `g`, I printed the network without vertices names (but with numbers instead of names). Why? Did I miss anythyng when I printed graph?

Comment: This is not a question about R and iGraph. It is a question about socnetv. If you look at your graphml file in a text editor, you will see that it does contain the node names in the file. Your question is how to make Socnetv use those names.